# Is there a way to run multiple big query data transfers at once?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have multiple data transfers running in the big query that load data from google cloud storage and update tables in bigquery. The issue is that sometimes the data is delayed from the source and the table don't update with the latest data in big query. I have to go and run each data transfer manually to update the table. Is there a way to run all my data transfers at once? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify how much delay you are facing and how you scheduled the transfer? Is your data updating in Cloud Storage continuously?

Comment: The data usually comes in around 7 am and we run an update around 8 before work. But sometimes the data is delayed.

Comment: Multiple transfers on the same bucket at a single time is not possible. For your requirement, I would suggest you ensure that data is not written while it's being transferred. You can consolidate the data first into one GCS bucket source by scheduling a copy to a temp GCS bucket, then perform a single BigQuery transfer from the consolidated storage bucket. Let me know if that helps.